# How much of the movie "Meet the Patels" is fiction and how much is real?

Tags: realism, meet-the-patels

Meet the Patels (2014) is an American romantic comedy documentary about an Indian-American who is of Gujarati origin and shows the cultural clash with his parents, focusing on marriage. I was wondering,

Do parents of Gujarati Americans really exchange "bio datas" of their marriageable aged children?

Also, has some of the story been staged for dramatic effect, like in reality shows?

Ok, after doing some research on IMDb, I found that the hero's love interest, Audrey, is a professional actor and is actually married to someone else in real life. It appears the work is more film than documentary, but need more information on this.

Comment: I don't know the answer, but Kamail Nanjiani (who's Pakistani, not Gujarati) shows his parents sharing head shots and similar things in his autobiographical movie "The Big Sick". So it's certainly something that rings true with people who come from that region. I'm not sure how exaggerated it is, though.